# How to calculate chances of beating two opponents with one card?

Tags: probability, card-games

SETUP:

- Standard 52 card deck. Game is O-hell.
- Trump game where any card from one arbitrary suit beats any other card from another suit.
- 3 players, A, B & C.
- A has the lead.
- Each player has one card.
- Hearts is trump, Ah (A of Hearts) is turned up and shown.
- Player A has a 2s (2 of Spades)
- Ace is high

QUESTION: What are the chances that player A will win the hand?

MY ANALYSIS:

- Out of 52 cards, player A knows about 2s and Ah. 50 unknown cards.
- There are 26 cards that a 2s will beat when A plays it. Any Club or Diamond.
- There are 24 cards that will beat his 2s. Any remaining Spade or Heart (trump suit).
- A's chances of beating B seems to be $\frac{26}{50}$.
- What are A's chances of beating B and C: I think it is $\frac{26}{50} \times \frac{25}{49} = 26.5\%$.

Is this how you approach this kind of problem, even while varying the number of cards each player has and the number of players in the game? If it is 4 players and 1 card, then $\frac{26}{50} \times \frac{25}{49} \times \frac{24}{48} $?

Is this an "n Choose k" problem instead?

Comment: We need the know how hands are played to answer this. Note that all we need to know are the rules that apply to the particular situation you are asking about. What do the players do in a hand? What determines the winner? For instance, in your analysis you say a 2 of spades beats any club or diamond. Yet you meantioned nothing that would indicate this elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Paul. Player A leads his 2s, follwed by Player B, then Player C. The winner is the the highest trump card (e.g. hearts) or in that absence, then highest space. So, if Players B and C only have diamonds or clubs, then A wins; else as just explained. Not sure I understand your final 2 sentences. These are the same rules as any basic standard 52 card game with trump. Hearts, Spades, Euchre, OHell, Poker, etc.

Comment: ** "space" = "spade" in my last comment.